# Adding this to a variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, this

I want to use a variable to cache several selectors in my jQuery code.

I seem to have hit a bit of a brick wall, as I'm not sure how to correctly add the 'this' keyword to my variable. For example, I have a variable defined as follows;

```
(function($){ var dropNav = $('nav ul li, span.arrow'); var dropDownNav = $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFour,u‌​l.dropNav').hide(); dropNav.hover(function(){ $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFour,‌​ul.dropNav',this).show(); },function(){ $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFou‌​r,ul.dropNav',this).hide(); return false }); })(jQuery);
```

As I'll be using this to show and hide navigation items I want to use the variable 'dropDownNav' with the 'this' keyword to target individual navigation items.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry: do you mean you want to use `this`, this being a DOM element, as the root element of your selector to find only those elements beneath the `this` DOM element? And you want to generate the selectors only once and re-apply this to `this` every time? (Is that really a performance problem?)

Comment: please explain more, in particular why you want to use `this` rather than any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a jQuery collection to a variable and use that as cache.for Example:

```
var dropDownNav = $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,ul.dropNav');
dropDownNav.hide();
dropDownNav.show();
```

you can use the cached variable to attach event handlers.

```
dropDownNav.click(function(){
  //here this refers to the clicked element
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after... instead of what you have do this:

```
var dropDownNav = $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,ul.dropNav'); //hide these in the css

dropDownNav.hover(
function(){ //onhover
$(this).show();
},
function(){ //mouse moves off
$(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I tried this solution and can't get it to work. Any idea why not?

Comment: can you supply example html of the page? I'm not sure what div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,ul.dropNav are so hard to say what's not working

Comment: This is what my current (somewhat messy) js code looks like

`code`
(function($){

var dropNav = $('nav ul li, span.arrow');
var dropDownNav = $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFour,ul.dropNav').hide();

dropNav.hover(function(){
  
 $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFour,ul.dropNav',this).show();
  },function(){
   $('div.dropDownNav,div.dropDownNavTwo,div.dropDownNavThree,div.dropDownNavFour,ul.dropNav',this).hide();
  return false
 });

})(jQuery);`code`

Comment: @webworker Please edit that into the question where you can format it properly - thanks!

Comment: sorry @webworker, afraid I still don't understand your code... can you post the html somewhere with nav items... use jsfiddle if you can't host it yourself. I think you are setting your variables wrong but can't be sure